# How to get dataline to mic and record get samples in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get microphone data line on an Android phone and get sound in to a byte buffer using particular sampling period. I coded this in Java using `TargetDataLine`. But it shows an error when working with Android. So is there some way to do this or can I use this `TargetDataline` as it is in Android? Thank you!

```
private void captureAudio(){
    try{
      audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
      DataLine.Info dataLineInfo =new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,audioFormat);
      targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
      targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
      targetDataLine.start();
      Thread captureThread =new Thread(new CaptureThread());
      captureThread.start();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      System.exit(0);
    }//end catch
  }//end captureAudio method
```

*

Comment: If you want some help you would probably do well to post some of the relevant code, and the error you are getting, by editing your question.

Comment: ok... Now i have provided code here. this tragetDataline does not allow to create in android, it shows a syntax error.

Comment: And what exactly is the syntax error it gives? Are you sure it's a syntax error though? A syntax error is a mistake in how you've written your code (not what it does);simple example a missing semi-colon in Java.

Comment: I found the solution, There is a class called AudioRecord in android instead of targetDataline in java. thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

DataLine is in a javax package, which does not work on Android's Java SDK. You would have to use Android's equivalent classes.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternatives of which you might be aware?

Comment: @battery https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord